# What can be an informal name for MSE?

Tags: discussion, meta, site-name

Formally, Meta Stack Exchange should be called as Meta Stack Exchange or MSE. But when writing on specialized sites, I frequently use:

> This has been discussed somewhere on the meta or the ____

What could be filled in the blank beside MSE? I once used "mother meta", but it doesn't really fit. I want to use something that can fill the blank more naturally.

The reason for that is because when the word "meta" is primed before, the later should also have a word "meta" explicitly, and in the form "adj + meta", not as a proper noun.

Comment: What on earth is wrong with just using MSE?! Nothing else you could think of, is both more efficient and more effective, and will never be a better combination of both factors.

Comment: This was also discussed on Stack Exchange's meta aka MSE.

Comment: Main meta is what I've taken to referring to it. MSE *ought* be universal, but is practically used for math and magneto stacks apparently as well.

Comment: "network-wide meta"

Comment: @Nij The reason for that is because when the word "meta" is primed before, the later should also have a word "meta" explicitly, and in the form "adj + meta", not as a proper noun.

Comment: I have also heard the term "Über-meta" (or "Uber-meta").

Answer (score -5, accepted):

"Main meta" seems more natural than "mother meta". MSE *ought* be universal, but depends on the site it can be understood as Math Stack Exchange, Mathematica Stack Exchange, or Magneto Stack Exchange.

<sup>Thanks Journeyman Geek and Laurel</sup>

Answer (score 6):

The only spellings I've ever seen for this site are "Meta Stack Exchange", "MSE", and occasionally "Meta SE". All of these are names most users will recognize. Any other name probably won't be recognized by most users. As for being "natural", an acronym is about as natural as you can get. I would highly recommend using "MSE" when you need an abbreviation.

Comment: The problem with the abbreviation MSE is that in some places it will be interpreted as referring to Math SE. Except when people think it refers to Mathematica SE.

Comment: @Laurel I usually see those labeled as Math.SE and Mathematica.SE. Meta SE is better in that there's no other acronym to get it confused with.

Comment: Unless someone reads "Meta SE" as "meta software engineering"... :)